# Array remains empty but data is being pushed by creating a temp array

Tags: javascript

I am writing a program to generate subsets of a given array in Javascript. I am pushing the subsets into another global variable array called subMegaSet. But when I access subMegaSet in another function, the array contains empty subsets. But if I push values by creating another temp array, the subsets are being pushed into subMegaSet. I am not able to debug this.

```
function createSubsets(nums, n, arr, index){
if(arr.length >= 0){
    let temp = [];
    for(let item of arr){
        temp.push(item);
    }
    // subMegaSet.push(arr) ----> Empty array pushed 
    subMegaSet.push(temp);
}

if(index === n){
    return;
}

for(let i=index; i<n; i++){
    arr.push(nums[i]);
    createSubsets(nums, n, arr, i+1);
    arr.pop();
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

There is only *one* `arr` array. Values get pushed to and popped from it, but it remains one, single array. This means that every time you do `subMegaSet.push(arr)` you add the *same* array to that `subMegaSet`. So it is not possible that `subMegaSet[0]` would be a different array than `subMegaSet[1]`, ...etc. At all indexes you'll find the same array. If at the end of the whole procedure that array has become empty, then all you will find in `subMegaSet` will be an empty array -- repeatedly.

This is why you need to *copy* the array into a new (separate) array, when you push it unto `subMegaSet`, so that you guarantee that:

- Any future `push` or `pop` on `arr`, does not affect the array that you just added to `subMegaSet`
- All entries of `subMegaSet` are different array instances.

You can simplify that copying using spread syntax:

```
subMegaSet.push([...arr])
```

Comment: Thank you got it now. arr is pointing to same memory location and at last it becomes empty after all pop() is done and hence it remains empty.  Yes, spread/slice would have been better for code readability.